# Alternatives to Nautilus that support a list of files to hide in .hidden

Tags: file-manager

Are there any good alternatives to Nautilus that support the same `.hidden` file? That is a file in which I can write file and directory names, and then the file manager hides them.

I have already tried to use Thunar, but it doesn't support using the `.hidden` file to hide other files and folders. Are there any alternatives which will?

I am currently using Debian (wheezy if it matters).

Note that this isn't a question about dot files: I want to customize the set of hidden files.

Comment: view -> show hidden files.

Comment: @jordanm, that's not the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nemo](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?p=198) does (in so far as I just tried this and it worked), but it's really part of [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) which is a replacement for the Gnome 3 shell. It does not appear to have any dependencies on Cinnamon, however.

It is in the repos for Fedora 17+ and Mint, of course. Probably others as well. [Github](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo) if you need the source.

On a further note, I had no idea about the .hidden file support in Nautilus (or Nemo) and I definitely like this.

Comment: Yea it's pretty useful for when programs create folders you can't rename, but don't wanna see :D

Comment: You can install nemo from a .deb file from Linux Mint's packages: http://packages.linuxmint.com/ the package is named 'nemo', but there are many packages that extend nemo as well. When I tried this method on Ubuntu 15.04 I had trouble with extended features never setting up and working properly, the core file browser worked though. (I would still use that over what Ubuntu ships).